# How can I use the GitHub CLI to download a release from a private repo?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-cli

I'm trying to download assets from a release on a private repository.

My current code would be:

```yaml
run: gh release download release -R Hostname/RepoName -D
```

This only works if the repository is public. Is there a way to get the assets from a private repository?

Comment: If this is an option, have you tried the Github API instead of the Github CLI? [Reference](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/47453)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide an Access token of the private repo/orgs. [From the doc of the CLI tool](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login):

```
To use gh in GitHub Actions, add GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }} to "env".
```

something like:

```
      - name: Download release from private repo
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}
        run: gh release download release -R Hostname/RepoName -D .
```

where `GH_API_TOKEN` is a valid PAT for access to the `Hostname/RepoName` repo.